# How to transform a matrix $A$ such that it has all its entries similar to an another matrix $B$ except its last row?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two matrices $A$ and $B$. I am looking for a transformation $TAT^{-1}$ such that all the entries of $TAT^{-1}$ are same as of $B$ except its last row so that I can get a matrix which contains all elements zero except its last row when I subtract $B$ from $TAT^{-1}$. Is there any idea?

Comment: I guess this is not possible to do for arbitrary matrices $A$ and $B$. For instance, if $A$ is the identity matrix, then $TAT^{-1}$ will be the identity matrix whatever $T$ is.

Comment: Then what are the possible cases for which it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let ${\mathbb M}_n$ be the space of all $n\times n$ matrices. For $i, j\in \{ 1, \ldots, n\}$, let $E_{ij}\in {\mathbb M}_n$ be the matrix with $1$ at the position $(i,j)$ and
with $0$ in the other positions (the standard basis for ${\mathbb M}_n$). Denote by $orb(A)$
the symmilarity orbit of $A\in {\mathbb M}_n$, i.e.,
$$ orb(A)=\{ TAT^{-1};\quad T\in {\mathbb M}_n\quad \text{invertible}\} $$
and let
$$ {\mathcal S}=\{ a_1E_{n1}+\cdots+a_n E_{nn};\quad a_1, \ldots, a_n \in {\mathbb F}\} $$
be the linear subspace of ${\mathbb M}_n$ of all matrices which have $0$ everywhere except in the last line. Then $A$ and $B$ can be connected in the prescribed way if and only if $B\in orb(A)+{\mathcal S}$. Of course, this is a trivial observation, however I guess that for a
general $A$ it cannot be said much more.